# Does software exist to create Flow Maps (for migration of people) on Mac?

Tags: mac, flow-map

Does anybody know a good, and easy to use, software to create flow maps?

I want to create flow maps for showing the flow of people between places (migration).

The software has to be compatible with Mac computers.

I have tried the plugin for QGIS, but it was designed for Windows.

Comment: Can you define flow maps in your context? Are we talking hydrology here, or something else? What is it that you want to show? What kind of data have you got available? Please expand on your question in order to get helpful answers (use edit button just below it).

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of different flow mapping software that work on Macs. Below are some links to pages where you can find more information about downloading these software:

Flowpy: http://www.enj.com/software/

Phan et. al Flow Map Layout: http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/flow_map_layout/

QGIS FlowMapper plugin: install plugin in QGIS

The QGIS flow mapper plugin, although designed for Windows, does work on Mac. It has a few glitches but gets the job done.